# Blank window in java

Tags: java, window, trigonometry

I am writing a java program that can graph a function on a created window. Everything was working until I started messing with cosine/sine. My program compiles but for some reason I get a blank window when I run it. It is supposed to be displaying an x and y axis with a cosine graph given the x values. I've been trying stuff all day and can't figure out what my logical mistake is is my code.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class PlotGraph extends JFrame{


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.drawLine(50, 300, 550, 300); //x axis
    g.drawLine(300, 550, 300, 50); //y axis
    //Orignin x = 300 y = 300

    double xmin, xmax;
    double y;
    xmin =(0);
    xmax = 100;
    double x = xmin;

    double form = Math.cos(x);

    double last_y = 300-(form);

    for (x = xmin+1; x<=xmax; x++){
    double newForm = Math.cos(x);
    y = 300-(newForm);
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x-1+(300), last_y, x+300, y));
    last_y = y;

    }




}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    PlotGraph graph = new PlotGraph();
    graph.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    graph.setSize(600, 600);
    graph.setVisible(true); 
    graph.setTitle("PlotGraph");
}
}
```

Comment: You're not adding the component you're painting to your JFrame

Comment: okay I am fairly new to java so I am unfamiliar to this concept.. 
Would it look something like.....graph.add(everything in my paint component)?

Comment: Please see the answer I provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the component you're painting to your `JFrame`.
What you need to do is for your `PlotGraph` class to extends `JComponent`, or a class that is a subclass of `JComponent` (`JPanel` or `JContainer` as suggested in the comment), and then add an object of `PlotGraph` to a `JFrame`.

For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    PlotGraph graph = new PlotGraph();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.add(graph);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setTitle("PlotGraph");
}
```

Your `PlotGraph` class should extends `JComponent` instead of `JFrame`:

```
class PlotGraph extends JComponent
```

As Legend mentioned you can have your class extends `JPanel` or `JContainer` for more functionalities if you like.

Comment: JPanel or JContainer would probably be better. Then you can `setContentPane()` and `pack()` better.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I understand now! I have it graphing but it just looks like a straight line and not really what a cosine function would like is there something missing for it to graph properly or are the points too small?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The structure of the graph looks like a cosine function. However if you want to draw the actual lines that represent the data this is another story related to how you actually draw the graph.

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame` is not a sub-class of `JComponent` and hence does not override the `paintComponent` method so the method is never called.

This is why it is advisable to add the `@Override` annotation to let the compiler perform the necessary method checking. You need to move this functionality to a sub-classed `JComponent` not forgetting to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

- [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)